# How to convert android.graphics.Color to androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm drawing a JetpackCompose `Canvas`

```
    Canvas(modifier = modifier.clipToBounds()) {
        val colorEvaluator = ArgbEvaluator()
        colorEvaluator.evaluate(t, Color.Red, Color.Blue)
        drawCircle(
            style = Stroke(8.dp.toPx()),
            color = AndroidColor.valueOf(colorEvaluator.evaluate(t, Color.Red, Color.Blue) as Int),
            center = Offset(size.minDimension/2 , size.minDimension/2),
            radius = size.minDimension * t)
        drawRect(
            color = darkColor,
            style = Stroke(16.dp.toPx()),
        )
    }
```

Where

```
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Color as AndroidColor
```

I got this error on `color = AndroidColor.valueOf(colorEvaluator.evaluate(t, Color.Red, Color.Blue) as Int),` where the error message is

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
Found:
android.graphics.Color
```

Comment: Read the error. Use your `Color`, not `AndroidColor`. Also check [the docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/themes#color). Try debugging to see the result type of `colorEvaluator.evaluate`.

Comment: @Nicolas: [`ArgbEvaluator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ArgbEvaluator) works in terms of `AndroidColor`.

Comment: @Elye: Since Compose UI is being set up to support cross-platform use, there would need to be an extension function somewhere to convert between `Color` types. I don't know if there is one built in. So, you might need to write your own, or consider porting `ArgbEvaluator` (it is [not that big](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/animation/ArgbEvaluator.java)), so you can stick with Compose `Color` consistently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like I should supply `AndroidColor.RED` and `AndroidColor.BLUE` to the ArgbEvaluator instead of accidentally use the `Color` of `Compose`

Where `AndroidColor` is `import android.graphics.Color as AndroidColor`

```
    Canvas(modifier = modifier.clipToBounds()) {
        drawCircle(
            style = Stroke(8.dp.toPx()),
            color = Color(ArgbEvaluator().evaluate(t, AndroidColor.RED, AndroidColor.BLUE) as Int),
            center = Offset(size.minDimension / 2, size.minDimension / 2),
            radius = size.minDimension * t
        )
        drawRect(
            color = darkColor,
            style = Stroke(16.dp.toPx()),
        )
    }
```

**Updated**

Found an even better approach, that is to use `lerp` in `compose` as per the below code. Using this approach, we no longer need to use the old `ArgbEvaluator`.

```
    Canvas(modifier = modifier.clipToBounds()) {
        drawCircle(
            style = Stroke(8.dp.toPx()),
            color = lerp(Color.Red, Color.Blue, t),
            center = Offset(size.minDimension / 2, size.minDimension / 2),
            radius = size.minDimension * t
        )
        drawRect(
            color = darkColor,
            style = Stroke(16.dp.toPx()),
        )
    }
```