# How to Convert androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color to android.graphics.Color (int)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to convert from Compose Color to Android Color Int?

I am using this code for the moment and it seems to be working, I can't seem to find a function to get the Int value of the color

```
Color.rgb(color.red.toInt(), color.green.toInt(), color.blue.toInt())
```

where `Color.rgb` is a function `android.graphics.Color` that returns an Integer color and color variable is just a Compose Color !

Since the float one requires higher API

Linked : [How to convert android.graphics.Color to androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64303405/3343503)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use the [`toArgb()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color).toArgb()) method

> Converts this color to an ARGB color int. A color int is always in the
> sRGB color space

Something like:

```
//Compose Color androidx.compose.ui.graphics
val Teal200 = Color(0xFFBB86FC)

//android.graphics.Color
val color = Teal200.toArgb()
```

You can also use something like:

```
//android.graphics.Color
val color = android.graphics.Color.argb(
      Teal200.toArgb().alpha,
      Teal200.toArgb().red,
      Teal200.toArgb().green,
      Teal200.toArgb().blue
    )
```

Comment: Gabriele thanks for this but there's a small error in your answer. The .blue and .green parameters need to be switched or you'll end up with an incorrect color conversion ;)

Comment: @dead_can_dance you are right, thanks for the feedback. Answer updated.

Comment: It's not necessary to use `toArgb` this way; looking at the example adove, we can simple do this: `val color = Teal200.toArgb()`

Answer (score 9):

The Android Compose `Color` class now has function [toArgb()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color).toArgb()), which converts to Color Int.

The function documentation says:

> **Converts this color to an ARGB color int.** A color int is always in the sRGB color space. This implies a color space conversion is applied if needed.

-> No need for a custom conversion function anymore.

Comment: This is a better solution !

Comment: I was already thinking of writing some custom solutions, but your answer saved me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me convert to Argb, then convert to string:

```
fun Int.hexToString() = String.format("#%06X", 0xFFFFFF and this)

fun getStringColor(color: Color): String {
  return color.toArgb().hexToString()
}   

fun someOperation() {
  val color = Color.White //compose color
  val colorAsString = getStringColor(color)
  print(colorAsString)
}


// Result will be: "#FFFFFF"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a spin on the answer from @gabriele with some Kotlin sugar:

```
//Compose Color androidx.compose.ui.graphics
val Teal200 = Color(0xFFBB86FC)

fun Color.toAGColor() = toArgb().run { android.graphics.Color.argb(alpha, red, green, blue) }

//android.graphics.Color
val color = Teal200.toAGColor()
```

Answer (score -6):

What worked for me is:

```
color.hashCode()
```