# How to convert android color to compose color

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to convert Android color to Compose color. But I don't know how.

I used these code but these codes have Error and my App crashes.

```
val currColor = task.startDate.time.toColor()
var test = lerp(Color.Red,Color.Blue,265f)
```

And

```
var test = Color(ArgbEvaluator().evaluate(20f,Color.Red,Color.Blue) as Int)
```

I checked that link too.
[How to convert android.graphics.Color to androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64303405/3343503)

So how can I convert android.graphics.color to androidx.compose.ui.graphics.color ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val graphicsColor = android.graphics.Color.RED
val composeColor = androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color(graphicsColor)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can convert it with

```
val int = android.graphics.Color.RED
val color = Color(int)
```

but you neither need conversion nor ArgbEvaluator().evaluate() to changer color based on fraction.

Compose has `lerp` function that takes two Compose Colors and fraction to change color based on fraction which is between 0f and 1f

lerp(Color.Red,Color.Blue,***265f***)

should be between 0f and 1f

```
/**
 * Linear interpolate between two [Colors][Color], [start] and [stop] with [fraction] fraction
 * between the two. The [ColorSpace] of the result is always the [ColorSpace][Color.colorSpace]
 * of [stop]. [fraction] should be between 0 and 1, inclusive. Interpolation is done
 * in the [ColorSpaces.Oklab] color space.
 */
@Stable
fun lerp(start: Color, stop: Color, /*@FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0)*/ fraction: Float): Color {
    val colorSpace = ColorSpaces.Oklab
    val startColor = start.convert(colorSpace)
    val endColor = stop.convert(colorSpace)

    val startAlpha = startColor.alpha
    val startL = startColor.red
    val startA = startColor.green
    val startB = startColor.blue

    val endAlpha = endColor.alpha
    val endL = endColor.red
    val endA = endColor.green
    val endB = endColor.blue

    val interpolated = Color(
        alpha = lerp(startAlpha, endAlpha, fraction),
        red = lerp(startL, endL, fraction),
        green = lerp(startA, endA, fraction),
        blue = lerp(startB, endB, fraction),
        colorSpace = colorSpace
    )
    return interpolated.convert(stop.colorSpace)
}
```

Comment: `lerp(Color.Red, Color.Green,.36f)` works with any value between 0f and 1f. When i try this code i see a color close to orange.